# Handling repeatingly repeated questions

Tags: discussion

I've recently noticed an increased incidence of questioners repeating their question if no reply (or one they can accept) is received toot suite or in a time scale of their choosing.

Often, they will delete their first attempted question before reposting or when the dupe is noted in comments, they will then delete the first incidence.

In one recent case, the question was answered but since the questioner seemingly didn't agree with the answer given, the question was again repeated.

Is there a policy on how best to handle this? Some questioners have become quite aggressive when challenged.

Comment: I think it's because the way closed questions are displayed encourages people to ask a new question

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Flag one of the posts for the mods.

Peer to peer discipline is tough on both parties, often ending in disagreements or worse. Let us handle the rougher edges. It's not just an authority thing, we can see more, including deleted posts, proper timelines, and might see why they're doing something —it's possible you might not be right— and then move onto contacting them in an official way, and if needs be, taking further action.